# perl split file with selective data

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to split a very large file into smaller files based string within the file. 
Along with the which I would like to filter non-required elements, by selecting only the elements desired in the list.

example input

```
 Block(A_1){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_footprint : 3BAA5927A22E66B0AE1214A806440F12;
   Block_Coordinates {
    values ("0 , 0",\
        "50, 50");
    }
   Block_connection : "North";
 }
 Block(BX_q_2_1){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_footprint : 3BAA5927A22E66B0AE1214A806440F12;
   Block_Coordinates {
    values ("20 , 20",\
        "20, 70");
   Block_connection : "South";
 }
 Block(C_2_r){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_footprint : 3BAA5927A22E66B0AE1214A806440F12;
   Block_Coordinates {
    values ("50 , 50",\
        "10, 500");
   Block_connection : "North-West";
 }
```

Output is three files 
grep Block_area & Block_Coordinates entries
The sample input has a lot of other data hence I would like to grep using regex.

A_1.txt

```
 Block(A_1){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_Coordinates {
    values ("0 , 0",\
        "50, 50");
    }
 }
```

BX_q_2_1.txt

```
 Block(BX_q_2_1){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_Coordinates {
    values ("20 , 20",\
        "20, 70");
 }
```

C_2_r.txt

```
 Block(C_2_r){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_Coordinates {
    values ("50 , 50",\
        "10, 500");
 }
```

I was earlier helped to split the file

```
while (<>) {
  my ($file) = m|\( (.+?) \)|x or next; 
  open my $fh, ">", "$file.txt";
  print $fh $_;
  close $fh;
}
```

alternately

```
while (<$in_fh>) {
  open $out_fh, '>', "$1.txt" if / Block \( (\w+) \) /x;
  print $out_fh $_ if $out_fh;
}
```

But I am not able to include selective data.

regards

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to remove the `Block_footprint` lines from the output files?

Comment: Yes; I wish that instead of removing data based on key words, I would like to include data based on Keywords

Comment: The input format is weird: there's no right curly brace for the Coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

To only output specific keywords, I'd use the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $OUT;
while (<>) {
    if (my ($filename) = /Block \( (.*?) \){/x) {
        open $OUT, '>', "$filename.txt" or die $!;
    }

    print {$OUT} $_ if ! /Block_/                         # header & inner values
                    or /Block_(?: area | Coordinates )/x; # keywords

}
```

It doesn't work if you need to skip multiline entries, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use `match` and `groups`

```
(Block\([^)]*\){(?:(?!\bBlock_connection).)*)
```

Try this.This will give all required groups.Set flags `s` and `g`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/41

or

you can split by `Block_connection\s+:\s+"[^"]+";\s+}`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/43

Comment: I am sorry that I dont understand your solution, but I didn't on how this would be used in achiveing the target of including Block_coordinates which is a multi-line entry

Comment: @user1495523 see demo.This will select the 3 blocks as well as multiline entry as `s` flag is to be used.